# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, spring-security

Логин Spring Security.
login.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.error {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
}

.msg {
    padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #31708f;
    background-color: #d9edf7;
    border-color: #bce8f1;
}

#login-box {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.loginForm.username.focus();'>

    <h1>Spring Security Login Form (Database Authentication)</h1>

    <div id="login-box">

        <h3>Login with Username and Password</h3>

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
            <div class="error">${error}</div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
            <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
        </c:if>

        <form name='loginForm'
            action="<c:url value='/login' />" method='POST'>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>User:</td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='username'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                        value="submit" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />

        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Здесь прочитал, что нужно добавить:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                    value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Но проблема все равно не решается. Как решить? Спасибо.

Comment: `<c:url value='/login' />` - думаю это не правильно. Откройте в браузере просмотр исходного кода страницы или инструменты разработчика (часто открываются по F12) Найдите там `form` и посмотрите какой там получился `action`. А теперь в исходном коде замените `<c:url value='/login' />` на `${request.contextPath}/login` или `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login`. Когда страница откроется опять найдите `form` посмотрите на `action`

Comment: @Sergey, не помогло.

Comment: Что не помогло? Та же самая ошибка?

Comment: @Sergey, да, все равно ошибка "HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported".

Comment: Тогда смотрите ещё как у вас написан контролёр в spring

Comment: Чтобы запрос прошел успешно на сервер, нужно выполнить несколько условий. Правильный url лишь одно из них. Что ещё не так по этому JSP Вам скажет только гадалка

Comment: @Sergey [вот мой контроллер](http://pastebin.com/RAZ9cqDz). Я совсем недавно работаю с этим, еще многого не понимаю.

Comment: Надо учить мат.часть. Знать как работает протокол HTTP, на котром вся эта хрень держится. Вот как помечен ваш `login`: `@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)` Так он принимает `GET` и _не принимает_ 'POST'. Вам нужно написать `method = RequestMethod.POST` чтобы принимал только `POST` или `method = {RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET`} чтобы принимал и `POST` и `GET`

Answer (score 1):

[Пример у Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-example/)

Если хотите более детального обзора, скиньте Security.xml и контроллер.

Answer (score 0):

1. В комментариях верно указано, что д.б. контроллер с маппингом, например @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST).
2. Проверьте конфигурацию SpringSecurity - возможно мешает csrf и его надо отключить
   `http.csrf().disable()`()`<http>...<csrf disabled="true"/></http>`
3. И да, не в обиду сказано, но RTFM никто не отменял :)